# Avoiding props bloat in parent react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say I have a functional react component that has 3 functional react child components (as is common when using redux with react). Is it common practice that the parent component props be the union of the props of all 3 child components? If not, how do you go about avoiding parent component props bloat?

Comment: read some on React Context

Comment: @Uzi React context is for passing down props that are considered global to the application. I'm asking more about genuine component props.

Comment: for global stuff, use a provider in your root. for specific, more local stuff, place your provider accordingly.

Comment: This might be the wrong forum for this question as it may be mostly opinion based. At minimum you may want to share some code or create a working example to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find a general answer for that. I'd say it heavily depends on the matter at hand.

- If you can handle the amount of props in the parent component, it's a valid option
- As some comments suggested `context` might be a solution in some cases
- State containers or stores (Redux, MobX) can be used for handling data across multiple components